# What is the API to tie a folder to a file (a la Internet Explorer)

Tags: windows, winapi

When you save an HTML file in Internet Explorer it creates a sub-folder with all its linked files.  These two are linked, so that when you delete the file the folder goes too.

I want to do the same thing in my app.  Can anyone give me a pointer to the relevant API?

Thanks

Comment: you can do it by coding the process yourself by manually finding the directory with the same name as the HTML file and recursively removing it.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that I want the file to be symbolically linked like this _outside_ of my application, so when they delete my apps file the folder is deleted too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pairing of HTML files and their attendant resource directory is a special case (implemented by the shell) and so is not a feature of the file system or to the best of my knowledge any extensible shell API. See *Connecting Files* in the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Thanks Alex, shame it can not be used for other purposes.

Comment: I was losing my mind that Windows was deleting the file too when I wanted to get rid of the folder. I think they did a terrible implementation of this. They need to add this as configuration in the file propertoes. I tried deleting from command prompt and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

When you have got the HTML file name, search that directory, in which the HTML file exists, for a directory with the same name as the html file but without the extension, and remove it recursively.